# What are your best practices when developing symfony 1.4 forms/widgets/validators?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, widget

I am currently working on some symfony form customisation which includes writing widgets or better still extending existing ones.

However this proves to be much more complicated as I thought it would as the functionality for validating, form elements, object saving, dynamic javascripts and so forth seem to be scattered all over the place. A lot of non default widgets that you can find are hard to extend as they often do not separate javascript not HTML.

So what should be the best practice form/widget development guidelines?

I would be willing to summarise such guidelines. Only now I am not too sure what they could look like. Lets brainstorm together!

Separate HTML from PHP
Put Javascript in extra files (unobstrusiveness)
Don't force your CSS styles upon others
Do not write gigantic methods but small extendable/overloadable ones
..
What do you think should also be included?

Original article can be found here:
http://test.ical.ly/2010/08/25/question-what-would-you-expect-of-a-best-practice-document-when-developing-symfony-1-4-form-widgets/

Comment: I really think that you should wait for symfony 2.0 to come out and after that we can storm our brains on the new platform. :)

Answer (score 1):

Amongst others mentioned in the article, don't hardcode form element id and name attributes in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var widget_id = "<?php echo $form['widget']->renderId() ?>";
    var widget_name = "<?php echo $form['widget']->renderName() ?>"; 
</script>
```

Comment: And if your JS is an included file? :-) but if you do the JS in the template, then I agree with this approach.

Comment: You only need to define your global variables in the template and you can reference them in the external files.